# Multidimensional array and pointer addressing

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int x[2][3] =
  {
    {4, 5, 2},
    {7, 6, 9}
  };
  int (*p)[3] = &x[1];
  int (*q)[3] = x;
  printf("%d %d %d\n", (*p)[0], (*p)[1], (*p)[2]);  //7, 6, 9
  printf("%d %d\n", *q[0], *q[1]);  // 4, 7
  return 0;
}
```

x[0] ----> [4, 5, 2].

x[1] ----> [7, 6, 9]

so if `p=X[1]`, `p[0]=7`, `p[1]=6` and `p[2]=9`, so the first printf is understandable.

For the second printf, `x` will be equal to the address first element of the array. If *q[0] is 4, why is *q[1] 7, shouldn't it be 5? It skips a row.

---

Actual output from link:

```
7 6 9
4 7
```

Comment: Shouldn't the output of `p` be 7, 6 and 9, since `p` points to the *second* array in `x`? Please edit the question to include the *actual* output (copied and pasted) from the actual program you show in the question.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I also got that: http://ideone.com/QPp5xd

Comment: you are correct, sorry fixed. Typed wrong row, but question stands.

Comment: It's a question about [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the array indexing operator `[]` have higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`.

Comment: You should really, **really** learn the basics of the language. This is trivially answerable using an operator precedence table…

Comment: If you think `p[0]=7, p[1]=6 and p[2]=9` and `(*p)[0], (*p)[1], (*p)[2]` are same then you are wrong. `p[0]` is a pointer and dereferencing it will give `7`, `*p[0] = 7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare these two lines:

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", (*p)[0], (*p)[1], (*p)[2]);  //7, 6, 9
printf("%d %d\n", *q[0], *q[1]);  // 4, 7
```

In the first line you have dereferenced the pointer first and then accessing the index - in your second line you're missing the parenthesis. Changing it to:

```
  printf("%d %d %d\n", (*p)[0], (*p)[1], (*p)[2]);  // 7, 6, 9
  printf("%d %d %d\n", (*q)[0], (*q)[1]);  // 4, 5
```

Will output the values as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

it is pointing to the second array in x.

If you want to get all elements of first row you can use something like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int x[2][3] =
{
{4, 5, 2},
{7, 6, 9}
};
int (*p)[3] = &x[1];
int (*q)[3] = x;
printf("%d %d %d\n", (*p)[0], (*p)[1], (*p)[2]);  //4, 5, 2
printf("%d %d %d\n", *q[0], q[0][1],q[0][2]);  // 4, 5,2
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Output you get is valid .

`*q[1]` is equivalent to `q[1][0]`  . And therefore , value at that index is `7` which you get as output .

To get `5` you can write like this `q[0][1]` or the other way to represent `(*q)[1]` .

Answer (score 0):

It's an operator precedence issue. `[]` has higher priority than unary `*`. If `[]` is applied to an array pointer, it will perform pointer arithmetic by the same rules as for regular pointers.

For any pointer type, `ptr[i]` equals `*(ptr + i)`, and `ptr+i` means "give me the address of `ptr` plus `i*sizeof(*ptr)` bytes.

So in your case `q[1]` means "give me the address of `q` + `1*sizeof(*q)`, where the contents of `q` is an array of 3 integers. So you end up pointing at the beginning of the 2nd array.